# Sybase/JDBC: how to detect reorgs or exclusive locks?

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase, reindex, table-locking

We use Sybase ASE (15.5) server as our DB and are having strange, intermittent SPID blocking issues that I am trying to detect and mitigate programmatically at the application-layer.

Sybase allows you to schedule so-called ["reorgs"](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands78.htm) which from what I can tell are periodic re-indexes/table compactions, cleanups, etc. Scheduled DB maintenance, basically.

Every once in a while, we get all the planets coming into alignment with each other, where:

1. A query is executed (creating a SPID in Sybase) and hangs for some reason. This places a (blocking) shared lock on, say, the `widgets` table; then
2. The scheduled reorg kicks off, and wants to cleanup the `widgets` table. The reorg places an exclusive lock request on `widgets`, but can't obtain the lock because `widgets` is already locked and blocked by the hanging SPID/query; then
3. Subsequent queries are executed, each requesting shared locks on `widgets`; such that
4. The whole system is now tied up: the reorg can't start until it obtains an exclusive lock on `widgets`, but `widgets` is tied up in a blocking shared lock by a hung SPID. And because the reorg has placed an exclusive lock on `widgets`, all other queries wanting shared locks on `widgets` have to wait until the reorg is complete (because a newly requested exclusive lock trumps a newly requested shared lock).

I think my ideal strategy here would be to:

- Timeout DB queries after say, 2 minutes, which will prevent SPIDs from hanging and thus preventing the reorgs from running; and then
- If a query attempts to hit a table that has an exclusive lock on it, detect this and hadle it specially (like schedule the query to run again 1hr later, when hopefully the reorg is complete, etc.)

#### My questions:

1. How do I timeout a query to release a shared lock after, say, 2mins?
2. Is there a way to programmatically (most likely through the Sybase JDBC driver, but perhaps via Sybase command-line, HTTP calls, etc.) determine if a reorg is running? Or, that an exclusive lock exists on a table? That way I could detect the exclusive lock and handle it in a special way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the commands that are running in the database with the following query:

```
select cmd from sysprocesses
```

To find locking information you can join `master..syslocks` and `your_db..sysobjects` to find out what locks exist on the object you are trying to access.  `syslocks.type` indicates the kind of lock that is in place, and those possible values can be found here:

```
select object_name(id), db_name(dbid), type from master..syslocks
where dbid = db_id("your_db")
```

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1550/html/tables/X16427.htm

Hopefully that helps.

To find if the lock is tied to a reorg, I think you should be able to join syslocks.spid to sysprocesses.spid where cmd = "REORG" or something like:

```
select p.cmd, p.spid, l.type from master..sysprocesses p, master..syslocks l  where CMD = "REORG"
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael Gardner (+1) - I guess just one more follow up. Is there a way to tell if an exclusive lock is on a table **and** that the lock came from a reorg SPID/process? Basically: does a `SELECT` query exist to determine if the reorg is currently running and operating on a given table? Thanks again!

Comment: To find if the lock is tied to a reorg, I think you should be able to join syslocks.spid to sysprocesses.spid where cmd = "REORG"

Comment: Thanks @Michael Gardner (+1) for all! Can I use `cmd = reorg` as-is or did you have an editing/SO issue? If so, should it be: `cmd = 'REORG'`? Thanks again!